# When setting TableViewHeader, the section header text is removed

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

When I programatically set the headerView for a UITableView, any sections will lose their section header text.

I'm just using this code to set the header after the view loaded (and a REST request has been made)

```
/* In the request response method */
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.alertView;
shouldShowBanner = YES;
[self.tableView reloadData];

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    if(shouldShowBanner){
        return self.alertView;
    } else {
        return nil;
    }
}
```

I create the view programmatically depending on the response I get from the server.  If I don't show a custom header, the section title works normally (as I set it in the Storyboard).  But as soon as it shows the section title goes away.

I tried using this method found in the delegate protocol

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return @"Section Title";
}
```

It's called, but doesn't seem to do anything.  Just to be clear, the view that I am creating does show without any problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A view can only have one parent. It (`self.alertView`) can't be in both the the table header view and the section header view.

Create separate views for both.

Also, do not implement both `titleViewHeaderInSection` and `viewForHeaderInSection`. Just one or the other. And if you do implement `viewForHeaderInSection` make sure you also implement `heightForHeaderInSection` too.

Comment: You're right!  I should've looked more closely at the method I was using.  I just wanted a header for the entire table, but I was setting it for each section.  I removed the `viewForHeaderInSection` method and everything works now.  I'll make your answer as correct as soon as I can.